# sap-ui-core.js - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: eclipse, sapui5, web-ide

I'm currently developing an app for school, but I ran into problem.
Couple of days ago, I made an application in webide. Developing went great and the application was successfully built. Now today, I wanted to re-run that same application but it stopped working. I made the same application with exactly the same code in Eclipse (Just copied the code from webide application) and it works great.

My program contains a table with a columnListItem press event. In the Webide, when I press it seems that the event is not executed while in the Eclipse version the event is executed.

When I look in my browser console while running the webide app I see following error: [image: Click here for the picture].

I don't think it's necessary to put my code here, because I know it works. But maybe you guys know that there sometimes are bugs/problems in the webide?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some differences from web-ide to eclipse, thats mainly the WebContent folder, you should check your ressources folder. The easiest way to transfer from WebIDE to Eclipse for me is to export in web ide, unzip it, copy it and insert it into a complete empty ui5-project (without webcontent-folder) ... I think theres a problem accessing ressources somewhere..

Comment: It's very strange but I checked again the application on WebIDE and it worked again. I think there are sometimes some bugs in WebIDE. But I'm happy that it works again. Thanks for you advice!

Answer (score 2):

do you have this reference in the index.html ?

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js" etc </script>
```

This uses a servlet to load so if that isnt running you get that error.
See the web.xml file in the project for more details.

You can point the **src=** at the standard OPEN CDN for the library and it should work.

```
<script
src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
</script>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answering! Yes I did this. If you wouldn't do this, the whole page wouldn't load. Strangly after some time the Webide version was working again. I think that there was a bug with Webide.Till now, I didn't encounter any more problems.